# Is using keywords without comma in title tag wrong in a SEO point of view?

Tags: seo, title

On the `<title>` tag of one of my webpages I used keywords without comma.

Is thist wrong in a SEO point of view?

Comment: Please give us an example.

Comment: "High Quality Decor Home Accents, Cheap wholesale Glass Candle Holders, Champagne Collection" this is the title. Is it wrong in seo point of view?

Comment: That looks like quite a spammy title to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write `<title>` tag for visitors and not for SEO. Thus, you must use a title easy to read and understand.

Whatever you put commas, hyphens or something else, just inserting keywords in the row is not easy to read or understand.

Answer (score 3):

Page titles should read naturally, whether they contain commas, other punctuation or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Google engineer Matt Cutts has said that: you can use any tag like commas, spaces, dashes, pipes in your title tag except for the underscore “_”.

But you have to use `<title>` tag according to your site theme which help visitors to understand your site easily.

Answer (score 0):

According to recent Google update, in  you can use keywords with separating by comma(,) or pipeline (|). The main point is, it should be simple to understand for the users. And the title is for the website's users as well as different search engines.